# Rails: Override Association Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am trying to create a relationship between `Server` and `Report`. The `Server` model `has_many :reports`.

The `Server` model has the following attributes

- id
- game_server_id
- name

The `Report` model has the following attributes

- id
- game_server_id
- installs

The problem I am facing is if I do the following

```
    class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :reports 
    end

   Server.first.reports
```

Rails will try to match a server up with its reports based on the `server_id` field in `Report` model. To solve this I could easily do the following

```
    class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :reports, source: :game_server 
    end

   Server.first.reports
```

Now, rails will try to find a server's reports, but matching `Server.id` to `Report.game_server_id`. This is not what I want!

I need rails to match `Report.game_server_id` to `Server.game_server_id`. Is there anyway I could change the configuration to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the foreign key in the association. You can see all of the options available for associations in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Try this:

```
has_many :reports, foreign_key: :game_server_id
```